# Difference between <itemtype generate="false"> and <model generate="false"/> in Hybris Models

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I wanted to understand the difference between  and  in Hybris for Model creation. How do they function internally?

Answer (score 0):

`<model generate="false"/>` can be used in some contexts:

1) In `<itemtype>` to exclude the type from being created (including all subtypes) and can be used like in this example:

```
<itemtype ....>
<model generate="false"/>
</itemtype>
```

2) In `<attribute>` context to exclude the attribute from being created. The result is that neither the private field nor getter and setter methods are generated!

```
<attribute ...>
<model generate="false"/>
</attribute>
```

I didn't found any utility yet for this case.

The `<itemtype generate="false/true"/>` is used to specify to generate the Java class files or not (for getters/setters).

You can read [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8c146aa686691014bbf6fe76a708ece2.html) more information about `<model/>` tag (create custom getters/setters/constructors for an itemtype)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sebastian but the point I wanted to understand was that if we do generate=false and keep model generate=true, what will happen for that particular itemtype. The link you provided I had already read but I wanted to get exact understanding of how it works internally.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but you didn't specified this in your question. The usecase I can think about is that in earlier versions of Hybris there was (and still is) a so called `Jalo Layer` and all the business logic was added in the itemtype's **jalo** class. Now, if you add the `<model generate="false"/>` the itemtype's **model** class is not getting created (which is used in the current `Service Layer`) so I assume that this `<model>` can help in improving the build time, less memory, less space etc. since you don't need this class.

Comment: Why would you need a business logic implemented in Jalo Layer if in the newest versions they're using the Service Layer? As far as I remember, there are some functionalities that still works in this Jalo Layer so maybe you want to override them or something..